# volume scattering light cycles 3.0; has some boxy areas

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

My scene has a volume scatter shader on a non rectangular shape and I am getting these unhappy blocky squares in my render.  See attached screen snippet.  As you can see, some of the light looks great-rays (upper left) and some look blocky (mid right and lower right).  Any suggestions on how to fix?  My current render settings also attached.  Getting a really nice image is priority over render speed.
[image]

Do I just need to keep increasing the max samples or look at some other setting? Note that I've made Step Rate Render for Volumes smaller and increased Max Steps
[image]

Here is my volume scatter ... is the shape of it the problem?
[image]

Comment: I would lean towards gpu/driver issue since the boxes are more in a tile pattern

Comment: @AllenSimpson I agree, because I think I’ve seen this before. What is OP’s graphics card?

Comment: two SLI enabled Geforce GTX 1070 Ti with latest driver and default settings for '3d settings' if those matter

Comment: so if this GPU/driver theory is correct, I can run the render overnight (and for the next 3 weeks :-) ) on my CPU instead of my SLI GPUs and the chonky blocks will be gone.  I'll give that a try tonight.

Comment: So after more testing, I've clarified that I do NOT always get the blockiness.  If I change the number of samples (much lower) and increase the size on the Z axis of my 'scatter box' everything looks much better, no blockiness.  So this seems more like a render problem than a GPU driver problem.

Comment: btw I have two intersecting volume scatter objects - one for the larger fog effect and one for 'low lying river fog'.  I seem to get more blocky effect with a higher samples number.  Maybe the intersecting scatter volumes don't work well together with high samples?